# Dynamically create a multi dimensional array in php from string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a piece of string that looks like this, which defines the structure of my array (generated from selected options in a JSTree):

> Dashboard_Tabs_Summary<#>Dashboard_Sections_Default_View<#>Clients_Tabs_Summary<#>Clients_Tabs_Quote
>   History<#>Clients_Tabs_Order
>   History<#>Clients_Tabs_Notes<#>Clients_Tabs_Contacts<#>Clients_Sections_Default_Create<#>Clients_Sections_Default_View<#>Clients_Sections_Default_Edit<#>Clients_Sections_Default_Delete<#>Dashboard_Tabs<#>Dashboard_Sections_Default<#>Dashboard_Sections<#>Dashboard<#>Clients_Tabs<#>Clients_Sections_Default<#>Clients_Sections<#>Clients

If I explode this string by `<#>`, I end up with these lines (sorted in logical order):

```
Dashboard
Dashboard_Tabs
Dashboard_Tabs_Summary
Dashboard_Sections
Dashboard_Sections_Default
Dashboard_Sections_Default_View
Clients
Clients_Tabs
Clients_Tabs_Summary
Clients_Tabs_Quote History
Clients_Tabs_Order History
Clients_Tabs_Notes
Clients_Tabs_Contacts
Clients_Sections
Clients_Sections_Default
Clients_Sections_Default_Create
Clients_Sections_Default_View
Clients_Sections_Default_Edit
Clients_Sections_Default_Delete
```

Is there a way to go from the above into an array structure like this:

[image]

Here's my attempt, but it's not working quite right:

```
<?php

$permissions = 'Dashboard_Tabs_Summary<#>Dashboard_Sections_Default_View<#>Clients_Tabs_Summary<#>Clients_Tabs_Quote History<#>Clients_Tabs_Order History<#>Clients_Tabs_Notes<#>Clients_Tabs_Contacts<#>Clients_Sections_Default_Create<#>Clients_Sections_Default_View<#>Clients_Sections_Default_Edit<#>Clients_Sections_Default_Delete<#>Dashboard_Tabs<#>Dashboard_Sections_Default<#>Dashboard_Sections<#>Dashboard<#>Clients_Tabs<#>Clients_Sections_Default<#>Clients_Sections<#>Clients';
$permissions = explode('<#>', $permissions);

$data = [];
foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    $p = explode('_', $permission);
    @list($p0, $p1, $p2, $p3) = $p;
    switch (sizeof($p))
    {
        case 4:
            $data[$p0][$p1][$p2][$p3] = null;
            break;

        case 3:
            $data[$p0][$p1][$p2] = null;
            break;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a reference to create the nested array:

```
$data = array();

foreach(explode('<#>', $permissions) as $permission) {
    $path = explode('_', $permission);
    $temp =& $data;
    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
}
print_r($data);
```